# how to loop through an array that its items get appended one at a time without repeatition

Tags: javascript

this is a multiselect dropdown list i didn't add the multiple attribute cause i didn't like its layout instead i push every selected element in selected=[],then when i try to loop through 'selected'array an input field gets created for 1st option then again for 1st and 2nd and as third option gets selected an input for 1st 2nd and 3rd so how to stop this repetition i get for three selected options 9 input fields

```
<select id="drugname" name="drugname" required>
              <option value="" selected></option>
              <option value="d1" >d1</option>
              <option value="2" >d2</option>
              <option value="d3" >d3</option>
            </select>
     <div id='put'></div>
    
     var selected= []
     function chooseOption(){
        let several= [...document.getElementById('drugname').options]
        several.forEach(option => {
                if(option.selected && option.value !=''){
                  selected.push(option.value)
    
    const selectit= document.querySelector('#drugname')
    selectit.addEventListener('change',()=>{ chooseOption()})

      
    selected.forEach(option=>{
        let input= document.createElement('input')
        document.getElemenById('put').append(input)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the selected array to an empty array after appending.

```
  selected.forEach(option=>{
    let input= document.createElement('input')
    document.getElemenById('put').append(input)
  })
  selected = []
```

Comment: But i am going to pair the items in selected with their input values after words so an empty array won't help can i loop over index instead of items ?!!

Comment: OK then when creating the input element assign an id to it. and check if the id does not exist when looping through selected.

Comment: the answer is much simpler no need to empty anything it costs only one line of code just one line it took me 2 or three weeks to figure it out